# Can a windows service start an application without being logged in?

Tags: c#, windows, service, windows-services

My question is one more of possibility then a how to.  I currently have two custom windows services, one sends files from the client to the host over a network using TCP, the other receives those files and once the transfer is complete launches a C# application that begins to upload those files to the database (Both servies do more but that is the basic idea on what they do).  My question is, is it possible to have the service running on the host(server) launch the C# application to upload without a user being logged in?  Or am I going to have to turn that application into a service as well?

Comment: You can have your service create an instance of the application which writes to the database.  The launched application cannot have a UI to it though

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> is it possible to have the service running on the host(server) launch the C# application to upload without a user being logged in?

That's the whole point of windows services - they run without anyone being logged in.

And yes, they can launch other processes - this is usually done via the [`Process`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.aspx) class.

```
Process.Start("path to application", "command line arguments");
```

You can use the returned `Process` reference and terminate it later on (if it is not self terminating) to ensure your server doesn't execute multiple copies of it and runs out of memory.

Comment: Thank you, I kind of figured that this was plosible I just need someone to verify that for me.  Thank you.